# How to exclude conditional on a column being missing and another having a specific value?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

Here's the thing, I have a dataframe called df which looks like this:

```
id        value
NaN       10
NaN       0
ATT       0
ARS       0
ABB       10
```

I want to exclude all lines when id is missing and value equals to zero.

I want to get this:

```
id        value
NaN       10
ATT       0
ARS       0
ABB       10
```

I've tried:

```
df[pd.isna(df['id']) & df['value']==0]
```

But it's not working and keeps excluding more lines than required.

Answer (score 3):

You need change (invert logic) - select all rows without `NaN`s or without `0`, also because priority operators add `()` for second condition:

```
df = df[df['id'].notna() | (df['value']!=0)]
print (df)
    id  value
0  NaN     10
2  ATT      0
3  ARS      0
4  ABB     10
```

Or use [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html), then `()` are not necessary:

```
df = df[df['id'].notna() | df['value'].ne(0)]
print (df)
    id  value
0  NaN     10
2  ATT      0
3  ARS      0
4  ABB     10
```

Or is possible invert original mask:

```
df = df[~(df['id'].isna() & (df['value']==0))]
print (df)
    id  value
0  NaN     10
2  ATT      0
3  ARS      0
4  ABB     10
```